# linq GeoCoordinate select based on two tables

Tags: c#, sql, linq

the 1st model represents the geodata

```
public class GeoData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string PlaceName { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }        
}
```

the 2nd model represents user's address

```
public class Address
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int GeoDataID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserID { get; set; }
}
```

GeoDataID being a FK to GeoData.ID

Given a convenient userid and range, I want to retrieve all Addresses in that range.
My first method

1. receives a userid and a range as an input
2. invokes another method returning the GeoCoordinate linked to user's address
3. invokes a static method asking for a List passing the user's GeoCoordinate, range and db context as params

   ```
   public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string userid, int range)
   {
           addressViewModel.Addresses = GeoDataController.getCoordinates(getGeoData(userid), db);
   ```

The static method should then be in charge for retrieving the GeoCoordinate(s) within the range and return a list of the Address(es) whose GeoDataID equals GeoData PK.

```
public static List<Address> getCoordinates(GeoCoordinate centerArea, GeoContext gdb, int range)
    {
        List<Address> PlacesInRange = new List<Address>();
            var query = from p in gdb.GeoData
                        select p;
            foreach (var geoArea in query)
            {
                GeoCoordinate geoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate
                {
                    Latitude = geoArea.Latitude,
                    Longitude = geoArea.Longitude
                };

                //adding to list only those Geocoordinates in a given range from centerArea
                if (centerArea.GetDistanceTo(geoCoordinate) < range)
                {
                //retrieve Address corresponding to current GeoData record
                Address AddressInRange = gdb.Addresses
                        .Where(a => a.GeoDataID == GeoData.ID).SingleOrDefault();
                // add found address to List
                    PlacesInRange.Add(AddressInRange);
                }
            }

        return PlacesInRange;
    }
```

This is not only quite awful, as I am retrieving all of GeoData records and then filtering... but does not work as when it comes to the Addresses...

```
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first
```

I won't spend any time to solve the open datareader issue, as there must a better and cleaner way to select from GeoData and Address tables, getting the expected Address list, provided GeoCoordinate(double latitude, double longitude) be in range of given user's Address.
Yet I can't manage to work this out, that is why any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use the [geography](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx) sql type?

Comment: I solved otherwise but thank you very much for the tip: good to know such a type exists!

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: Changed request: I had to change the return type to List<GeoData>